# NGINX/Django: 403 error when serving static files

Tags: python, django, nginx

I've spent many, many hours debugging this, and have not quite come to a solution yet. I've tried applying the solutions from the dozen or so relevant threads, but none solved the problem (that or I implemented the solution wrong).

I'm trying to serve media and static files using nginx and django, and am using a media file to test with (following [this tutorial](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html)). The logs show that it's trying to grab the correct file, but it just doesn't have the permissions to do so (`failed (13: Permission denied)`). Everything is set to 755. My nginx.conf and mysite_nginx.conf are as follows. Any ideas?

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log debug;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
} 
http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log  main;
    sendfile            on;     
    keepalive_timeout   65;    
    index index.html index.php;  
    include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite_nginx.conf; 
}
```

mysite_nginx.conf

```
upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}



server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;
    root       /var/www/;

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.access.log  main;

    location / { } #go to default index.html

    location /media/  {
        alias /Users/meep_me/Desktop/ram_stuff/combining/box/mysite/media/;  # your Django project's media files
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /Users/meep_me/Desktop/ram_stuff/combining/box/mysite/static/; # your Django project's static files 
    }

    location /other {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /Users/meep_me/Desktop/ram_stuff/combining/box/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Comment: ```/Users/meep_me/Desktop/ram_stuff/combining/box/mysite/media/``` do each of the folders have the +x bit set for permissions (usually required to list/access a fold/subfolder)

Comment: Oh wow. I thought everything was covered, but turns out just /Desktop didn't have it set. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/Users/meep_me/Desktop/ram_stuff/combining/box/mysite/media/`: Do each of the folders have the `+x` bit set for permissions (usually required to list/access a folder/subfolder)?

Answer (score 1):

The fix was as mentioned by warath-coder in the comments. I forgot to explicitly make sure *every* single folder actually had the +x bit set. Going through and finding the one that didn't solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, attempt to grant o+w and o+r permissions to upper-level folders.
Suppose I have an Ubuntu user.

```
chmod o+w /home/ubuntu/
chmod o+w /home/ubuntu/static_folder
```

it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).